How do I get the profile url from Amplify?
How do I get the profile attribute from the user so I can display a profile image? The structure of the user object does not contain it
    import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

    function App({signOut, user}) {
      console.log(user)


      return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <StandardCardCollection />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default withAuthenticator (App);


Eventually I used
import { fetchUserAttributes } from 'aws-amplify/auth'

async function handleFetchUserAttributes() {
  try {
    const userAttributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
    console.log(userAttributes);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

This does provide all the correct values
